# How did the Germanic languages evolve front rounded vowel phonemes

Tags: germanic-languages, proto-germanic

Proto-Germanic did not have front rounded phonemes. Why do most of its descendants have front rounded vowels?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this first and editing to address specific questions you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front rounded vowels in Germanic came from a process called "umlaut" ("altered sound"), where back vowels become front before a front vowel in the next syllable. Since those back vowels were rounded, the resulting front vowels were also rounded.